# No success in adding Leaflet.markercluster-1.4.1 to a Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet.markercluster

I had a fully working map with over 800 markers displayed and needed to cluster the markers. The code is quite long to retrieve the marker data and so I did not include it.

Should  Lealfet.markercluster work with the latest Leaflet versions?

I upgraded to using Leaflet 1.9.3. I also use JQuery v2.2. I have no other software added. I expected the software to provide clusters and not crash the page with error 500.